# php serialize const

Tags: php, serialization, constants

is it possible to serialize object like this , with const property?

```
class A
{
   const XXX = 'aaa';
}
```

i guess no, but what is solution?

Comment: yes, it nothig store, only public props

Comment: why would you like to serialize the const ? can't you just access it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `const` is not an object property, it's a class constant. That is, it pertains to your class and not any of its objects. It's also why you refer to class constants using `A::XXX` rather than `$this->XXX`.

Therefore you can't serialize that `const` with your objects, just like you can't serialize any static variables.

However, when you unserialize the object you will obtain it as an instance of that class, so you can just refer to the constant using the class name:

```
$class = get_class(unserialize($A_obj));
echo $class::XXX;
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to serialize and instance of a class that contains a `const` property, of course.

But **that `const` property will not be present in the serialized string** : no need for it, as it's constant : when the string will be unserialized, it'll be an instance of your class -- and, so, have that constant property, from the class' definition.

Serializing an instance of your class :

```
class A {
   const XXX = 'aaa';
   function test() {
       echo A::XXX;
   }
}

$a = new A();
$str = serialize($a);
var_dump($str);
```

You'll get :

```
string 'O:1:"A":0:{}' (length=12)
```

The constant is not present in the serialized string.

De-serializing works :

```
$b = unserialize($str);
var_dump($b);
```

And, if you try calling a method on that `$b` object, obtained whe unserializing :

```
$b->test();
```

The constant is indeed *found*, as it's in your class' definition, and you'll get :

```
aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
class A
{
   const XXX = 'aaa';

}
$a = new A();
$b=serialize($a);
$c=unserialize($b); // copy of the $a obj
```

but you can access cont by this way  `A::XXX;`